# Is there any way to copy some class and dont change the real one?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

```
class A
{
// constructor,destructors and some getter and setter functions.

friend A& operator+(A& x,A& y);
}

class B
{

vector <A*> A_s;
}
```

Assume here is `A n1*=new A("P");` and `A n2*=newA("R");` ( No special meaning of P and R ,I just wrote that to indicate these two are different objects.After that i want to do that :
 `A  final= *n1 +*n2;` and i dont want to change final, if i changed n1 or n2 (or vice versa).Is there any way to do that ? (I have no copy constructor for that,there is just default copy constructor).Since the real code is realy long, i tried to simplfy it , sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Really hard to understand you. Try simplifying your question description a lot and only leave information really needed.

Comment: Does your class A accept a constructor with Node? Otherwise i think you want to be friend with: `friend A& operator+(A& x,A& y);`

Comment: @Jiwan sorry its my mistake, i replaced it .

Comment: `final` will be its own object. Modifying `*n1` or `*n2` won't have any effect on it.

Comment: @sftrabbit What happens if A contains references or pointers? It's not a deep copy.

Answer (score 2):

First, the return type on your operator is probably wrong. You should return by value since you're returning a new object that's the sum of the other two. Also, you can take the first parameter by value and use that as working space to return. Finally you should take the second parameter by const reference, to avoid accidentally mutating your operands.

```
friend A operator+(A x, const A& y);
```

After that it's just up to your implementation of `operator+` to not leave references back to `x` and `y` and what you want will happen automatically!

Comment: Well, if his class A don't own references or pointers, modifying final won't affect final and vice-versa.